# precise64 vagrant box provisioning with Chef-solo fail

Tags: vagrant, chef-solo, berkshelf

### Installed on Mac OS X 1.9.2 Maverick

- [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/)
- [chef-dk](http://www.getchef.com/downloads/chef-dk/mac/)

### Initialized vagrant box

```
vagrant init .
```

### Berksfile

```
source "https://api.berkshelf.com"

cookbook "vim"
cookbook "git"
cookbook "npm"
cookbook "nvm"
cookbook "nodejs"
```

#### Fetched cookbooks

```
$ berks vendor
```

### Vagrantfile

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 8081

  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "berks-cookbooks"
    chef.add_recipe "vim"
    chef.add_recipe "git"
    chef.add_recipe "npm"
    chef.add_recipe "nvm"
    chef.add_recipe "nodejs"

  end

end
```

### Started the box

```
$ vagrant up
```

These errors appeared when I changed from chef/ubuntu-13.04 to hashicorp/precise64

### The Errors

```
[2014-05-07T13:03:23+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.12.4 ***
[2014-05-07T13:03:23+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 1704
[2014-05-07T13:03:30+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[vim]", "recipe[git]", "recipe[npm]", "recipe[nvm]", "recipe[nodejs]"] from CLI options
[2014-05-07T13:03:30+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[vim], recipe[git], recipe[npm], recipe[nvm], recipe[nodejs]]
[2014-05-07T13:03:30+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [vim, git, npm, nvm, nodejs]
[2014-05-07T13:03:30+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for precise64
[2014-05-07T13:03:30+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2014-05-07T13:03:30+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2014-05-07T13:03:31+00:00] INFO: WindowsPackage light-weight resource already initialized -- overriding!
[2014-05-07T13:03:31+00:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for package[curl] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2014-05-07T13:03:31+00:00] WARN: Previous package[curl]: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/npm/recipes/default.rb:26:in `from_file'
[2014-05-07T13:03:31+00:00] WARN: Current  package[curl]: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/nvm/recipes/default.rb:29:in `from_file'
[2014-05-07T13:03:31+00:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for package[build-essential] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2014-05-07T13:03:31+00:00] WARN: Previous package[build-essential]: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/build-essential/recipes/_debian.rb:24:in `block in from_file'
[2014-05-07T13:03:31+00:00] WARN: Current  package[build-essential]: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/nvm/recipes/default.rb:34:in `from_file'
[2014-05-07T13:03:31+00:00] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for package[libssl-dev] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2014-05-07T13:03:31+00:00] WARN: Previous package[libssl-dev]: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/nodejs/recipes/install_from_source.rb:27:in `from_file'
[2014-05-07T13:03:31+00:00] WARN: Current  package[libssl-dev]: /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/nvm/recipes/default.rb:37:in `from_file'

================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[vim]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '100'
---- Begin output of apt-get -q -y install vim=2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 ----
STDOUT: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgpm2 libpython2.7 python2.7 python2.7-minimal vim-common vim-runtime
  vim-tiny
Suggested packages:
  gpm python2.7-doc binfmt-support ctags vim-doc vim-scripts indent
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgpm2 libpython2.7 vim vim-runtime
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python2.7 python2.7-minimal vim-common vim-tiny
4 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,603 kB/13.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 28.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python2.7 amd64 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found
STDERR: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-minimal_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
---- End output of apt-get -q -y install vim=2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 ----
Ran apt-get -q -y install vim=2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 returned 100


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/vim/recipes/package.rb

 30:   package vim_base_pkg
 31: end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/vim/recipes/package.rb:30:in `block in from_file'

package("vim") do
  action :install
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  package_name "vim"
  version "2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1"
  cookbook_name :vim
  recipe_name "package"
end



[2014-05-07T13:03:32+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2014-05-07T13:03:32+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-05-07T13:03:32+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-05-07T13:03:32+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-05-07T13:03:32+00:00] ERROR: package[vim] (vim::package line 30) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '100'
---- Begin output of apt-get -q -y install vim=2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 ----
STDOUT: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgpm2 libpython2.7 python2.7 python2.7-minimal vim-common vim-runtime
  vim-tiny
Suggested packages:
  gpm python2.7-doc binfmt-support ctags vim-doc vim-scripts indent
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgpm2 libpython2.7 vim vim-runtime
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python2.7 python2.7-minimal vim-common vim-tiny
4 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,603 kB/13.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 28.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python2.7 amd64 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main python2.7-minimal amd64 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found
STDERR: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-minimal_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7_2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
---- End output of apt-get -q -y install vim=2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 ----
Ran apt-get -q -y install vim=2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 returned 100
[2014-05-07T13:03:32+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Any hint is welcome

Answer (score 4):

Based on the output, the error is obvious. APT was not able to get the Vim package from the US mirror.

TO resolve the issue, run an `apt-get update` within the VM and try again, if issue persists, try to switch it to a different Ubuntu update mirror by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`. e.g. switch to the main (with no `us.` prefix)

Try NOT to specify vim version in the vim cookbook, it is generally NOT a good idea at least for Debian/Ubuntu.

```rb
package("vim") do
  action :install
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  package_name "vim"
  cookbook_name :vim
  recipe_name "package"
end
```